# Chamar uma função quando um fragment é fechado

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tenho uma `activity` que chama um `fragment` que é exibido na forma de um `DialogAlert`. Porém, quando esse `fragment` é fechado, preciso que um método da `Activity` seja chamado. Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

O código da Activity:

```
package activities;

import classes.Event;
import adapters.EventListAdapter;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import br.bytecode.tarefas.R;
import database.Database;
import fragments.ViewEventFragment;

public class EventsActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_events);
        loadEvents();

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(
                (new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        Event event = (Event) parent
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        ViewEventFragment viewEvent = ViewEventFragment
                                .newInstance(event);
                        viewEvent.show(fm, "frag_view_event");
                        return true;
                    }
                }));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_events, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu_events_new:
            Intent newEvent = new Intent(this, ManagementActivity.class);
            startActivity(newEvent);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_events_logoff:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadEvents();
    }

    public void loadEvents() {
        Database db = new Database(this);

        EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(this, db.readEvents());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

O fragment que quero que dispare a função ao ser chamado está dentro do método `onItemLongClick`.

Comment: ViewNewEvent é um `DialogFragment`? Você quer executar algo quando o Dialog é fechado por cancelamento ou assim que for fechado (não importando como)?

Comment: Sim, é um DialogFragment. Quero que seja executado quando for fechado, não importando como.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça algo assim...

```
public class MeuFragment extends Fragment
{
    private OnFragmentClosedListener onFragmentClosedListener;

    public OnFragmentClosedListener getOnFragmentClosedListener() {
        return onFragmentClosedListener;
    }

    public void setOnFragmentClosedListener(OnFragmentClosedListener onFragmentClosedListener) {
        this.onFragmentClosedListener = onFragmentClosedListener;
    }


    @Override
    public  void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();

        //chama o callback
        if(getOnFragmentClosedListener() != null)
            if(getOnFragmentClosedListener().onFragmentClosed();
    }

    /**
     * Listener para ser chamado quando o fragment for "desamarrado" da activity
     */
    public interface OnFragmentClosedListener{

        public void onFragmentClosed();
    }
}
```

Na sua activity você usa esse Fragment ok... e implementa o callback dele..

```
MeuFragment meuFragment = new MeuFragment();
meuFragment.setOnFragmentClosedListener(new MeuFragment.OnFragmentClosedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFragmentClosed() {

    }
});


    beginTransacttion..... // faz aquele transição para adicionar o fragment a activity
```

Answer (score 1):

Para esse tipo de informação sobre o `Dialog`, a classe `DialogFragment` implementa duas interfaces: A [`DialogInterface.OnCancelListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) e a [`DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) que fornecem a informação que precisa. O `DialogFragment` já se registra automaticamente no `Dialog` que é construído internamente.

O `OnCancelListener` é chamado quando cancelado por interação do usuário (`backpress` ou botão negativo). Já o `OnDismissListener` é mais genérico e é chamado para os mesmos casos do `OnCancelListener` além da chamada ao método `dismiss` do `Dialog`.

Para usar esses dois `Listeners`, só através da sobrecarga dos métodos [`onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) ou [`onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCancel%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) que o `DialogFragment` possui:

```
public class ViewEventFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

        // Tratar o evento de dismiss do Dialog
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);

        // Tratar evento de cancelamento do Dialog
    }
}
```

Ao sobrecarregar esses métodos, sugeriria criar um `Listener` para ser notificado nesses dois pontos.

Comment: O ADT não está reconhecendo a função `setOnDismissListener`: `setOnDismissListener cannot be resolved or is not a field`. Eu preciso criar esse método no `ViewEventFragment`?

Comment: Hmm, erro meu, vou alterar a resposta para incluir o código correto. O problema é que tem que registrar um desses dois `Listeners` no `Dialog` desse `Fragment`. Vou incluir isso na resposta.